# AJAX autocomplete not working inside user control why?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

My AJAX auto-complete function is not working with a user control but when I use it with a normal ASP.NET page it works fine:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPConnection"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string CmdText = "select name+ '-' + ' ['+CONVERT(VARCHAR, custid) +']'as name from ht_cust where name like @City+'%' and EmpID =@EmpId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", prefixText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", contextKey);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    List<string> CityNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CityNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }

    return CityNames;
}

aspx code
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" onkeyup="SetContextKey()" CssClass="input-1" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>  
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCity" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCity" UseContextKey="true" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement">
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Share your code first

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a `webmethod` through a user control because it will be automatically rendered inside the page. Move your `webmethod` to your `aspx` page.

If you want the logic inside the controller then you can call it from aspx page but your `webmethod` needs to be in `aspx` page.

Example:

In aspx page:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{
  return mycontrol.GetCity(prefixText, contextKey);
}
```

In your user control :

```
public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPConnection"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string CmdText = "select name+ '-' + ' ['+CONVERT(VARCHAR, custid) +']'as name from ht_cust where name like @City+'%' and EmpID =@EmpId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", prefixText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", contextKey);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    List<string> CityNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CityNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }

    return CityNames;
}
```

Comment: sir how to create the object of  mycontrol in aspx.cs page

Comment: please Can any  answer this question?

Comment: zaki sir can you explain how you have created the user control inside the web method

Comment: you don't create an object of your contol. When you put your control in aspx file it will have an attribute of runat="server" and id. I assumed your id would be mycontrol...

Comment: but my usercontrol is an ascx file Zaki How will i implement your code in that.

Comment: In your aspx page's designer you need to include your control : <%@ Register Src="Controls/mycontrol.ascx" TagName="mycontrol" TagPrefix="ctrl" %> Then somewhere in page you need to add it : <ctrl:mycontrol ID="mycontrol" runat="server"  /> this way you have access to mycontrol in your code behind

Comment: ok its fine zaki, But mycontrol is not accessible inside web method  in the following line return mycontrol.GetCity(prefixText, contextKey);

Comment: sorry my bad i meant to say call your control class and your method inside control(as it is static you shouldn't have problem)

Comment: mycontrol in this ocassion would be your class name of ascx control